# Extract filename from the end of file path, not anywhere else in file path

Tags: python, filenames

I'm trying to extract filenames from several different paths. All is well except that my RegEx is also capturing the installer names or `.tmp` filenames that precede the filenames.

Here is a sample list:

```
logs = ['C:\\\\Users\\\\Administrator\\\\Desktop\\\\KeyFinderInstaller.exe({tmp}\\\\OCSetupHlp.dll)',
        'F:\\\\NOKIA N70\\\\RICAMI\\\\700 ESEMPI\\\\PCStitch 7.0.13 + Keygen(programma per punto croce)\\\\keygen.exe',
        'F:\\\\Programmi & Utility Pc\\\\Nero 8 (conversione film & creazione videosuonerie)\\\\keygen.exe',
        'C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\Desktop\\\\BloodHound-win32-x64\\\\BloodHound-win32-x64\\\\resources\\\\app\\\\Collectors\\\\SharpHound.exe',
        'C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\Desktop\\\\BloodHound-win32-x64\\\\BloodHound-win32-x64\\\\resources\\\\app\\\\Collectors\\\\DebugBuilds\\\\SharpHound.ps1'
        ]
```

The RegEx is as follows:

```
filename = [re.sub('\\\\','',re.search('\\\\[\w-]+\.\w{3}',log).group()) for log in logs]
```

Output:

```
['KeyFinderInstaller.exe', 'keygen.exe', 'keygen.exe', 'SharpHound.exe', 'SharpHound.ps1']
```

Desired Output:

```
['OCSetupHlp.dll', 'keygen.exe', 'keygen.exe', 'SharpHound.exe', 'SharpHound.ps1']
```

As you can see, the regex returns `KeyFinderInstaller.exe` instead of `OCSetupHlp.dll`. To make a long story short, I need the filenames that come at the very end of the path, not anything else in between.

Also, I'd like to get rid of the `\\\\`, but clearly my `re.sub()` solution isn't working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253484/discussion-on-question-by-overflowstack-extract-filename-from-the-end-of-file-pa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For entries similar to the ones in your sample, this works (the `.strip()` is used to remove the closing parenthesis).

```
filename = [log.split('\\\\')[-1].strip(')') for log in logs]
```

If there may be 'junk' after the last filename (instead of just the parenthesis), the following should work for more entries:

```
filename = [re.findall(r'\\([-\w]+\.\w+)', log)[-1] for log in logs]
```